# Problems with twig in cyrillic

Tags: twig

I'm trying to use twig template that contains my native language characters and receive this error

```
object(Twig_Error_Syntax)[173]
  private 'lineno' (Twig_Error) => int 1
  private 'name' (Twig_Error) => string 'sms' (length=3)
  private 'sourceCode' (Twig_Error) => string 'Привет, {{name}}' (length=22)
  protected 'message' => string 'Unexpected token "end of template" of value "" in "sms" at line 1.' (length=66)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected 'file' => string '/var/www/bitrix/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/ExpressionParser.php' (length=62)
  protected 'line' => int 201
```

However the same code works fine with Latin characters.

The code I use follows:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(['sms' => $arTemplate['PROPERTY_SMS_VALUE']['TEXT'], 'mail' => $arTemplate['PROPERTY_EMAIL_VALUE']['TEXT']]);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

try {
    $sms_text = $twig->render('sms', ['name' => $_REQUEST[FIELD_NAME]]);
```

It basically takes twig from database and applies simple render. I use twig without Symfony (only basic requirements installed)

Comment: Please post your exception as text instead of an image! :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use [tools.twig](https://github.com/maximaster/tools.twig) for bitrix CMS.

```
composer req maximaster/tools.twig
```

Then you should delete **template.php** and create **template.twig** file in component folder.

In the docs you can find [bitrix variables](https://github.com/maximaster/tools.twig/blob/master/docs/twig_extension.md) available in the twig template and rule for template [inheritance](https://github.com/maximaster/tools.twig/blob/master/docs/syntax.md).